# Programmatically changing compression level of Hadoop DefaultCodec

Tags: hadoop, compression, zlib, codec

I have a compression stream defined as below. How do I set the compression level from default level of -1 to, say a value of 8? The compressor that is created based on "DefaultCodec" is Zlib.

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
DefaultCodec codec = new DefaultCodec(config);
CompressionOutputStream zlibOutputStr= codec.createOutputStream(dataOut);
```

I created a Hadoop Configuration instance, `config`, which can be passed to the codec, but I don't know how to specify the configuration values, or which key/value pair to use for specifying compression levels. I looked at this too: [Uses of Configuration](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/class-use/Configuration.html).

Comment: What is your Hadoop version? I am not sure compression level property. Can add any source related to it?

Comment: Hadoop-2.6.2. source: https://github.com/facebookarchive/hadoop-20/blob/master/src/core/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/DefaultCodec.java